# What is the purpose/use case of log shipping monitor server?

Tags: sql-server, log-shipping

When configuring log shipping, under the restore section we can configure alert to get a notification if restore doesn't occur on the secondary in x minutes.

[image]

So then, what is the purpose/use case of monitor server?

And can we set either the primary or secondary as monitor server, or does this need to be a separate instance?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

A Monitor server can monitor a whole log shipping topology, eg:

[image]

From [About Log Shipping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/log-shipping/about-log-shipping-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16)

In SQL 2000 Log Shipping was an Enterprise Edition feature and a flagship HA/DR solution, so it's got some capabilities that are rarely used today.